# Can't get NIC driver to load in ThinStatinon build

Tags: linux, thin-client

Hoping to get some help here. The [ThinStation](http://thinstation.github.io/thinstation/)/DevStation site seems to be lacking IMHO. What I am trying to do is simple: repurpose an older computer (Dell Optiplex 745 SFF) as a thin client. I'm still in the testing phase, but if this works I'll be replacing Windows on all of our "scan station" computers with this since they only work in an RDS session and do not need Windows locally.

I have [DevStation](https://github.com/Thinstation/thinstation/wiki/DevStation-setup) up and running in a VM. I have ran Start > DevStation > Build Image (GUI) and Terminal command: `/thinstation# ./setup-chroot`

Also, I tried the command:  `./build --allmodules`
But it just returns:
`Checking for requires commands... FAIL
You are missing the following UNIX commands: comm
This build system requires them; aborting build`

I took the ISO from `/thinstation/build/boot-images/iso` and wrote it to a USB key via Live Linx utility. But when I boot to the USB key I have no NIC driver. Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess no one here uses DevStation/ThinStation. The fix for me was to just **reinstall DevStation**.